# Prevent MathJax to manipulate dom on startup

Tags: javascript, math, markdown, mathjax

I want MathJax to only manipulate certain elements on my page when I tell it to do so.

I've this code.

```
var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
converter.hooks.chain("preConversion", removeMath);
converter.hooks.chain("postConversion", replaceMath);

$(".exec-math").each(function(index, el){
  var str = converter.makeHtml($(el).html());
  $(el).html(str);
});

MathJax.Hub.Config({
 tex2jax: {
   inlineMath: [ ['$','$'] ],
   processEscapes: true
 }
});

MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);

// <span class="exec-math">**Markdown** and $a > b$</span>
```

It basically keeps the math away from the markdown engine.

The problem right now is that it looks like MathJax is being ran twice, like this.

1. MathJax is loaded, manipulate dom
2. Execute my code and schedule another run

**So, is there a way to tell MathJax not to run on startup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Set `skipStartupTypeset` to `true` in your configuration.  See the [core options](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html) documentation for details.